# "indulger of" vs. "indulger in"

Tags: meaning, idioms, differences, writing

A person can **indulge in *something***. Is he therefore an **indulger of *something*** or an **indulger in *something***? Are both okay?

If both are okay, is there any difference between these two phrases or are their meanings exactly the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve never seen either of those used. Logically, it would be **in**, but I’ve never seen that form. The *Corpus of Contemporary American English* is of the same opinion, and further points out that **indulger** is not widely used at all (and mostly by itself: “he was an indulger”).

Comment: I want to use the phrase in a humourous and quasi pretentious way. It's a bonus if it's not widely used or even strained as long as it is valid. :)

Comment: @darius then go for the logical construct: “an indulger in sugar”

Comment: Problem is 'indulger of' fits better the way I want to use it. I want to know if it's completely off the track.

Answer (score 2):

The *Corpus of Contemporary American English* contains the following sentence:

> Was Jackson an indulger in and practitioner of nostalgia?

The sentence is used only in academic context, though, with a frequency of 0.01 per million.

Looking for *indulger for* doesn't return any result.

Answer (score 2):

Indulge *in* means you yourself indulge; indulge *of* means you allow or enable indulgence in others.

I indulge in chocolate.  I am indulgent of my daughters' appetite for clothing.

I don't think "indulger" is a real word.

Comment: _Indulger_ is a word reported from the dictionaries (and not as example of a not existing word).

Comment: You can make most verbs into nouns by adding -er, but that doesn't mean *anyone else* will use that word.  "Indulger" only gets 66,000 hits on Google; c.f. 331,000 for "syzygy" (a technical word in astronomy, almost unknown among the general public), 122,000 "fahgettaboudit" (a phonetic rendering of "forget about it"), and 30,500 for "mofga" (a nonsense word I just made up -- admittedly, many of the hits were for the Maine Organic Farmers and Gardeners Association)